# What can be said about $f^{-1}$ when $f$ has no inverse?

Tags: inverse-function

Let $f: A \to B$ be given by $f(x) = |x|$, such that $A = [-1,0] \cup [1,2]$ and $B = [0,2]$.

I understand that $f$ does not have an inverse, since $f(-1) = f(1)$.

However, albeit my textbook is saying $f$ does not have an inverse $f^{-1}: B \to A$, it is also saying $f^{-1}$ is not continuous on $B$. How can that second sentence be made since $f^{-1}$ does not exist?

Comment: Perhaps the textbook intended to take $A = (-1,0] \cup [1,2]$.

Comment: But in that case $f$ would have an inverse. Unless the author was thinking about the interval $[-1,0]$ at the first statement, and the interval $(-1,0]$ at the second.

Comment: Did the author state that $f$ has no inverse **and** that $f^{-1}$ is discontinuous?

Comment: Yes. In the exact words,
a) $f$ does not have inverse $f^{-1}: B \to A$; and
b) $f^{-1}$ is not continuous on $B$.

Comment: It is impossible for $f$ to not be invertible *and* for $f^{-1}$ to be a discontinuous function anywhere, because if $f$ is not invertible, then by definition, $f^{-1}$ does not exist. It is nonsensical to use the symbol $f^{-1}$ when talking about functions that are not invertible. The very usage of the symbol assumes $f$ is invertible. So I think the author of the book likely made a mistake.

Comment: For clarification, can you tell us what book we are using here? Perhaps we can check for context what the author meant.

Comment: It's a portuguese book. It was a comment on some exercise that appeared couple years ago in an exam.

Comment: @Lenora Interesting.

Comment: @Lenora Well, in any case, let us hypothetically suppose that the author did mean $A=(-1,0]\cup[1,2],$ which makes $f$ invertible. Then it makes sense to discuss whether $f^{-1}$ is continuous or not. And we can conclude it is not continuous at $1$, but continuous everywhere else. If you graph it, I think it will be clear why.

Comment: Sometimes $f^{-1}$ is also used to refer to the map $f^{-1}(y) = \{x \in A : f(x) = y\}$

Comment: Comments often undergo far less scrutiny than the main text. My suspicion is the author meant that if the domain of $f$ were restricted so that $f$ becomes invertible, that inverse would not be continuous.